# Как избавиться от варнинга 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.ControlObjectsVisibility' is obsolet&

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В нашем командном проекте на teamcity возникает слудеющий варнинг warning

> CS0618: 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.ControlObjectsVisibility' is
>   obsolete: 'This property is obsoloete in RadAsyncUpload'

Данный варнинг генерируется следующим кодом

```
ControlObjectsVisibility="RemoveButtons"
```

Чем можна заменить данный функционал, чтоб вышеуказанный варнинг не генерировался?. Заранее все спасибо